# RegEx how to use correctly to check str

Tags: javascript

Trying to use RegEx but doesn't work...what i've missed?How to alert message when it is  "/0" in my calculator?

```
function div(input) 
    {
        var input = document.getElementById("t").value;
        var is_div_by_zero = /\/[\s.0]+$/.test(input); 

        if (is_div_by_zero)
        { 
            alert(" / to Zero");     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `/\/[0.]+$/` regex with `test()`.

Comment: The regex solution won't work, what if I write 5 / (5-5) or even 5/(0)

Answer (score 3):

No need to do this with a regex, check the number value instead. E.g.

```
if (!Number(document.getElementById("t").value)) {
    alert("Division by zero")
}
```

This will cast the value as a number and, when casted to a boolean, check if it's truthy or not. E.g. the value `'1'` will be casted to `1` which is `true` whereas `0` is `false` and `'foo'` is `NaN` which is `false`.